# How to install libmudflap in 64-bit 14.04 "Trusty"

Tags: gcc

I wish to demonstrate mudflap working on this program,

```
int
main()
{
  int tab[10];
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    tab[i] = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

but I get an error,

```
$ gcc -fmudflap -lmudflap bounds-violation.c 
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:59:1: fatal error: mf-runtime.h: No such file or directory
 #endif
 ^
compilation terminated.
```

So I need the mudflap libraries. But there doesn't appear to exist an appropriate library for my x86_64 platform:

```
$ uname -a
Linux orca 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ apt-cache search mudflap
lib64mudflap0-dbg-powerpc-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (64 bit debug symbols)
lib64mudflap0-powerpc-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (64bit)
libhfmudflap0-armel-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (hard float)
libhfmudflap0-dbg-armel-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (hard float debug symbols)
libmudflap0-4.7-dev-armel-cross - GCC mudflap support libraries (development files)
libmudflap0-4.7-dev-armhf-cross - GCC mudflap support libraries (development files)
libmudflap0-4.8-dev-armhf-cross - GCC mudflap support libraries (development files)
libmudflap0-4.8-dev-powerpc-cross - GCC mudflap support libraries (development files)
libmudflap0-armel-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries
libmudflap0-armhf-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries
libmudflap0-dbg-armel-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (debug symbols)
libmudflap0-dbg-armhf-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (debug symbols)
libmudflap0-dbg-powerpc-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (debug symbols)
libmudflap0-powerpc-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries
libsfmudflap0-armhf-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (soft float)
libsfmudflap0-dbg-armhf-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (soft float debug symbols)
```

Why all the ARM and Armel stuff? Searching on the net suggestions there should be a package called `libmudflap0-4.8-dev`, corresponding the preinstalled version of GCC in Trusty, but it doesn't exist.

Is this a bug? If not, how to I install libmudflap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't realise that mudflap has been deprecated in GCC from version 4.9. Even though Ubuntu 14.04 ships 4.8, I guess they have discontinued the package. Look up [AddressSanitiser](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer) instead.